# Cant acces concrete 5 via localhost

Tags: concrete

I've downloaded latest concrete 5 version from their website. After that I unzipped it into xampp/htdocs folder and when I'm trying to acces it via localhost it says this "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "Patchwork\Utf8\MB_OVERLOAD_STRING".

Im attaching a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

[Sorry I forgot to post it on original question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrEss.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

too late to answer but I think this may help some one searching the same issue. It seems to be a php version issue. Most probably old c5 version and you are on PHP8 or above. Try downgrading php version will fix it.